# Loading Gif on Select by ID

Tags: javascript, css, image, loading, gif

I'm trying to write "loading gif javascript library" for my own project. 
My question is how to place a loading gif on any image element by use their id?

```
#back {
  z-index: 1;
}
#front {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
}
```

There is https://jsfiddle.net/uvqxbrfj/2/ example but in my case my back images are already defined and assume that i know image id but i can not change their position attribute.

Any suggestion?

Comment: you start with the loading image as the image url and then change it with js when you are ready - ie when the image is preloaded or the laoding gif is scrolled into view, etc.  I'm guessing you are trying to do image lazy loading? there are plenty of plugins out there for that

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.